# GA: Distinguish source of an Event for session vs. campaign

Tags: google-analytics

I want to be able to differentiate a session which starts off with a direct `utm_source=Xyz` and a subsequent session from the same visitor which might have started through organic traffic.

My report examines GA Events that takes place at the end of the session.
Currently the second type of session also the `Source` set to `Xyz` (because this is set in a cookie for 2 years).

If I try to examine the `Full Referrer` value, it is also set to `Xyz` rather than `example-xyz.com` for both sessions (this seems like a bug).  The `Referral Path` is coming up as `(not set)` also.

Any way of distinguishing between the initial session and subsequent sessions?

I'm looking at the report in Behaviour -> Events -> Top Events, but can also create a custom report.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a [sequence segment](http://analytics.blogspot.gr/2014/04/new-user-and-sequence-based-segments-in.html) (first interaction Xyz then any other) or examine [conversion paths](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1329505?hl=en&ref_topic=1191164) in the Multi Channel Reports (assuming the event you examine is set as a goal)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to create a sequence segment as follows: https://imgur.com/OxROtkh
and also a traffic sources segment:
https://imgur.com/kL2eoj6
But neither worked (neither got rid of the event from the subsequent session)

Comment: I also triggered another event today (without a utm_source) to make sure that I've definitely created a new session.